# Populating a Cell based on the value of another cell?

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to calculate an hourly pay rate based the quantity of product being produced. Different quantities ordered will require different pay rates to produce the product. 
Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

If D2(The Quantity) is between 1 and 25 Display F29( Hourly Rate 1)

If D2(The Quantity) is between 26 and 50 Display F30( Hourly Rate 2)

If D2(The Quantity) is between 51 and 100 Display F29( Hourly Rate 3)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: =IF(D2>25,IF(D2>50,IF(D2>100,F31),F30),F29) 

This displays the 1 - 25 and 26 - 50  rates, but won't show the 51 - 100 rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(D2,{1,26,51})+28)
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. Are you able to give a brief explanation of how this works? What is the +28?

Comment: See [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)